# Strategies for multithreaded singleton object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I have a compelling use case where notifications happen in realtime at the server level. I would like to push these events out over a websocket using Rails' ActionCable. **How Can I reliably maintain a long-lived singleton object to react to and push server-level events?**

- I prototyped a Rails app using an object instantiated from a file in /app/lib that mixes in the `Singleton` module. Even with class caching, this was instantiated multiple times and occasionally garbage collected despite open sockets.
- Marking the event producer's `initialize` method private and writing a class-level instance method that checks `Thread.main[:event_provider]` for an instance works 95% in development, but I worry about what I don't know that I don't know about production. Very occasionally I get exceptions like "Expected x_y.rb to define constant XY" exceptions, which make me think there's a problem to this approach.
- The production server will ultimately serve a very small number of clients in an environment that demands 100% uptime. I can choose a server stack that makes sense.

I'm hoping someone with knowledge of Rack and/or ActionCable can comment on reliable ways to serve events to a Rails application from within the server.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ _“Expected x_y.rb to define constant XY”_ messages have nothing to do with reliability, it’s Rails ‘smart’ autoloading complains about your files naming / path.

Comment: _Sidenote #2:_ To _“reliably maintain a long-lived singleton object to handle server-level events”_ one rare if never picks up Rails solutions. The generic approach would be to use something like message queue (sending events there from your Rails,) and have a reliable app (reliable excludes Rails in the first place) that reads a queue, sends an event to consumer(s) and _then_ acks the message. That way it’d be guaranteed each message is processed.

Comment: Did you consider using iodine's built-in support for pub/sub? You can use it with ActionCable (though less recommended than direct pub/sub to raw WebSockets) by adding a code block to the subscription (so the subscription calls the block instead of sending the data)... (P.S., I'm biased)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin One approach that we're considering is a subprocess that connects to the Rails app locally, probably as a websocket client. Part of my motivation here is to learn a bit more about how ActionCable manages to be long-lived within Rails, and if it's possible (or advisable) for third parties to accomplish the same.

Comment: @Myst Looking at that now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As of now, the strategy I am undertaking is to instantiate a singleton object early in the boot process and then use it to maintain threads. Threadsafe practices are obviously needed for this.

The file application.rb defines `MyApp::Application`. At this point I declare an accessor `my_thing_manager`, `require my_thing_manager` and set `self.my_thing_manager = MyThingManager.instance`.

```ruby
class MyThingManager
    def instance
        return Thread.main[:thing_manager] unless Thread.main[:thing_manager].nil?
        Thread.main[:thing_manager] = self.new
    end

    private

    def initialize
    end
end
```

**This approach works in a single multithreaded process** but does *not* work in a clustered production environment. For my requirements that is completely acceptable. For a multi-process app, one could utilize hooks in e.g. Puma `after_worker_fork` or Unicorn's `after_fork` to manage a subscription to something like Redis pubsub. This will be a requirement for an upcoming project so I expect to develop this strategy further.